# mootools slideshow2

Tags: mootools, slideshow

i am using slideshow2 by Aeron Glemann in a website.Does in generate the thumbnails or do i have to provide them?the images iam showing are coming from a cloud, and are passed to the slideshow in an array.the thumbs exist in the cloud. how can i pass them in the array if the show cannot create them?
i have used the replace parameter with regex but it shows as thumbnails the full image and nothing happens when i alter the css properties for the thumbnails. the images are displayed.

here is the line for the show creation:
var myShow = new Slideshow('show', eval(res.value), { controller: true, height: 350,overlap: false, resize: false, hu: '',replace:[/^\S+.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$/,'t$1'],thumbnails: true, width: 600});

the value object contains the images from the cloud in format shown below:
['xx.jpg','yy.png',....]

thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your regular expression is broken. To add a 't' to the end of the filename? Try:

```
replace:[/^(\S+)\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$/,'$1t.$2']
```

Best to play with the regular expression using an [online tester](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) to get it right.

Comment: i took the expression from the faq of the site of the author.it is supposed to create a file name for the thumb by adding a 't' at the end of the file name, that the thumb comes from.

Comment: i can't see how that regex is meant to work. it only captures the file extension. i've updated my answer to perform the file name conversion: 'xx.jpg' => 'xxt.jpg'